# Login Form with PHP without refreshing

Tags: php, function, authentication, call

I have a login form, which I validate via PHP. The problem is, that the action of the form is referencing to the file itself, so that it's gonna refreshing the page. I don't like this. Is it possible to check the inputs via PHP without refreshing the page?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     session_start();

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

     $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

     // Benutzername und Passwort werden überprüft
     if ($username == 'admin' && $passwort == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

            // Weiterleitung zur geschützten Startseite
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
                if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
                    header('Status: 303 See Other');
                }
                else {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
                }
            }

       header('downloadbereich.php');
       exit;
       }
      }
?>

<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="contactForm" id="contactForm" style="width: 500px; margin: auto; float: left;">


<form name="myform" method="post" action="login.php<!-- this is what I want to remove-->">
    <p class="form" style="width: 245px; height: 116px; margin-right: 10px;"><input class="field" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
    <input class="field" type="password" autofocus name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort" />
    <button class="button" name="Submit">Login</button></p>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use jquery for this

Comment: is it easy? I actually copied the code which I found in the internet as I don't know how to use js or ajax or php

Comment: If you don't know how to use js or ajax or php, then obviously you have to learn them before using techniques, which require then all in once. I don't think a beginner should start with an AJAX login without basic knowledge.

Comment: ja I know... but it's just for personal use!

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this ready-to-use jQuery Ajax-Form Plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery - AJAX:

```
$.post('login.php', {
    username : $('input[name=username]').val(),
    password : $('input[name=password]').val()
});
```

Comment: and how do I implement this into my code? Sorry for asking

Comment: You must include the jquery.js, and put it in a script tag like this: `<script>$(function() { %CODE ABOVE% });</script>`

Answer (score 1):

call ajax at this page and your page will not refresh. ajax has a post page calling that calls the page but doesn't refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: create an iframe in the page and post to that.

```
<div id="somediv">Not logged in"</div>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="page_to_post_to.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" >
    //your form
</form>
```

inside *page_to_post_to.php*  you can do whatever you want. Feedback to the main page can be given with a bit of javascript, referencing to the parent.

```
<php
//do your stuff here
?>
<script>
window.top.window.document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML='logged in';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the form action to the php file which should check the inputs and return the errors or success back to the parent page/form. Use an iframe as form-target.

You can use jQuery for it like this (in the login.php):

```
parent.$('#submitStatus').html('there were some errors');
```